# AzureDevOps Build failing cant reach Microsoft.WebSite.Publishing.targets. unknown VStoolspath

Tags: c#, azure, msbuild

my project fails to build because it cant reach `Microsoft.Web.Publishing.targets` on Azure DevOps

Our `VStoolsPath` on Prem is `'C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v12.0'` and with `'\Web\Microsoft.WebSite.Publishing.targets'` is able to build.

I was wondering how do we find out what is the `VStoolsPath` for `AzureDevOps`? how do we find the same/similar path to get to `Microsoft.WebSite.Publishing.targets` to allow us to build our code?

Our csproj file is configured like this:

```
<Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props" 
        Condition="Exists('$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props')" />

<Import Project="$(VSToolsPath)\Web\Microsoft.Web.Publishing.targets" 
        Condition="'$(VSToolsPath)' != ''" />

<Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v$(VisualStudioVersion)\Web\Microsoft.Web.Publishing.targets" 
        Condition="false" />
```

This is the error I am getting:

> src\Automation.Agent\Automation.Agent.csproj(4,11): Error MSB4226:
> The imported project "$(VSToolsPath)\Web\Microsoft.Web.Publishing.targets" was not found.

> Also, tried to find "$(VSToolsPath)\Web\Microsoft.Web.Publishing.targets" in the fallback search path(s) for $(VSToolsPath) - "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v15.0" .

> These search paths are defined in "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\15.0\bin\msbuild.exe.Config". Confirm that the path in the  declaration is correct, and that the file exists on disk in one of the search paths.
> Process 'msbuild.exe' exited with code '1'.

Answer (score 0):

Whoops, found out I was using an incorrect agent to build.

Had to go to Agent pipeline - Azure Pipeline,  then agent specification is set to 'vs2015-win2012r2'

Answer (score 0):

I have added these lines for  and  in  my .csproj file it worked for me.

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <VisualStudioVersion Condition="'$(VisualStudioVersion)' == ''">16.0</VisualStudioVersion>
    <VSToolsPath Condition="'$(VSToolsPath)' == ''">$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v$(VisualStudioVersion)</VSToolsPath>


<Import Project="$(VSToolsPath)\WebApplications\Microsoft.WebApplication.targets" Condition="'$(VSToolsPath)' != ''" />
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v16.0\WebApplications\Microsoft.WebApplication.targets" Condition="false" />
```